# Customizing VBA button in Excel ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say we have code that prints a variable's value.

```
Dim ii as String
ii = "This is a test"
MsgBox(ii)
```

The code is run by pushing a button, in the Excel ribbon, linked to the VBA code.

Is there any way to set the value for the variable "ii" in the Excel ribbon, adding a bit of user friendly customization to the VBA code?

Preferably the user could right click the button to change the variable's value, and Excel would remember this change for all workbooks.

Comment: Yes and no. You can't do it the way as described. But you could use something like `ii = Selection.Value`. This way you could "read" the actual selected cell. Or use `ii = InputBox("Code?")` to insert a string. To make it work for all open workbooks is a different part which is related to the actions you want to do...

Comment: i think that the only way is to use an InputBox ... in your code that you posted, change _Msgbox(ii)_  to     `MsgBox(InputBox("Text ?", "Title"))` ... it will ask for an input and then display it in a messagebox

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [Microsoft tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c) to add a button to the ribbon and have it call a VBA macro.

Global variables must be stored in a standard module or in the document module. If it needs to be initialized when the workbook is opened, regardless of where it is stored, the value must be set either during WorkbookOpen event, or by a macro called by this event. Just in case, here is a link to the [Chip Pearson event tutorial](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

If the value of your variable needs to be preserved between sessions (uses), then it will have to be saved to a cell in a worksheet. Hidden or very hidden worksheets work well for this purpose. If the value is reset between sessions,  you can hardcode a default value in the module.

This should be all you need to get going. You will probably have to use a few macros to get the exact result you are looking for. Ultimately, this will depend on what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish data to be persistant for a particular machine or user. Store the users data in the registry.

Simply load the registry at the start of the macro. Provide an option using a text box, combo box, tickbox or whatever to allow the user to except the default values or make their own changes and then save the choices back into the registry.

This way it may be personalised for a particular user.

typical functions are

The registry values are stored under a fixed location (*I don't believe this can be altered from within native VBA*). Use this key if you wish to interrogate settings through the windows registry editor:

```
"MyComputer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\"
```

To read a registry value use your modified version of the following VBA code

```
GetSetting("MyApp","MySection","MyKey","My Default Value")
```

To Write a regisry value:

```
SaveSetting("MyApp","MySection","MyKey","MyValue")
```

For more information see [Better Solutions](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/registry-category.htm)

Mark